# How do I temporarily disable a submit button for 3 seconds (onsubmit), then re-enable it?

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I am fairly new to using javascript and here is what I have so far:

```
<!-- this is to disable the submit button and then re-enable it after 3 sec -->

<script type="text/javascript">

    function enable()
    {
    var x = document.LAYOUTFORM.getElementById("create_button");
    setTimeout(x.removeAttribute("disabled"), 3000);
    }

</script>
```

And for the button I have this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE=" Create PDF " class="FORMBUTTON" ID="create_button" onclick="javascript:this.disabled=true;javascript:enable();">
```

I have messed with this for hours and most of you will look at it and know what is wrong immediately.  My form ID and name is LAYOUTFORM. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

For bonus points I would also like the text of the button to temporarily change to "Creating..." while it is disabled, and then back to Create PDF again.

Comment: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: That's a lovely idea! Thank you.

Comment: AmazingChase please accept an answer.

Answer (score 14):

Simplest way:

```
<input ... onclick="lockoutSubmit(this)">
```

In your javascript:

```
function lockoutSubmit(button) {
    var oldValue = button.value;

    button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    button.value = '...processing...';

    setTimeout(function(){
        button.value = oldValue;
        button.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: awesome.. Thanks :) I was messing around setTimeout() 1st parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can access the button either by `id` that is globally unique 
or by the `name` unique to the enclosing form

So you have to either

```
var x = document.getElementById("create_button");
```

or

```
var x = document.LAYOUTFORM.elements["create_button_name"];
```

(Assuming create_button_name is the name of the button:

```
<input type="submit" value=" Create PDF " id="create_button" name="create_button_name"  class="formButton" onclick="javascript:this.disabled=true;javascript:enable();">
```

)

The first parameter of the setTimeout should be a function:

```
setTimeout(removeAttr, 3000);

function removeAttr() {
    x.removeAttribute("disabled")
}
```

BTW, HTML need not be (and should not be, for readability etc) all uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the LAYOUTFORM between document and getElementById.

Just an fyi, using firebug, chrome developer tools, or whatever the equivalent tools are for IE, you can monkey with your javascript on the console.  Console.log will also output text and even objects (in CDT) which you can inspect.  Very useful for exploring :)

Answer (score 0):

Several problems. First, in the onclick attribute, you use javascript: which is for URLs. Stuff inside the onclick attribute is already evaluated as code. Second, the code in your setTimeout should either be string or a function name. You should do something more like this:

**HTML:**

```
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE=" Create PDF " class="FORMBUTTON" ID="create_button" onclick="disable();">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function disable() {
        x=document.getElementById("createbutton");
        x.disabled=true;
        x.value="Creating...";
        setTimeout(enable, 3000);
    }

    function enable() {
        x.disabled=false;
        x.value=" Create PDF ";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry lets try that again... Hey thanks for the help.  I wasn't even close.  The button now changes and disables and changes back, but it didnt submit the form anymore.  I moved the disable() call to an onsubmit within the form tag and everything works perfectly.  You rule!

Comment: Good, glad it worked. You can delete that previous comment by hovering over it and pressing the small x.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with your JavaScript:

1. The `.getElementById()` method belongs to `document`, not to your form (or any other) element.
2. `setTimeout()` expects the first parameter to be a function (or a string, but there's almost never a situation when using a string is appropriate).

Try this:

```
function enable() {
    var x = document.getElementById("create_button");
    setTimeout(function() {
       x.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }, 3000);
}
```

You may like to combine the disabling and re-enabling into a single function:

```
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" ... onclick="temporaryDisable(this);">

function temporaryDisable(el) {
    el.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
       el.disabled = false;
    }, 3000);
}
```

Note that you don't need to use `.removeAttribute()`, you can just set the `.disabled` property directly (like you were already doing when you disabled the element).

EDIT: Just saw the "bonus points" part of your question. You just need to set the `.value` property:

```
function temporaryDisable(el) {
    var oldLabel = el.value;
    el.value = "Creating...";
    el.disabled = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
       el.disabled = false;
       el.value = oldLabel;
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, now I have 2 options on how to do this.  Maybe this will help someone else with the same problem in the future.  Google didn't have much for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disDelay(obj){
obj.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
setTimeout(function(){obj.removeAttribute('disabled')},30000)
}
</script>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="disDelay(this)">
```

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?164239-Temporarily-Disable-Submit-Button